# Simplify this expression 1/(3-√2)^2

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to simplify 1/(3-√2)^2 ?

Does the ^2 mean you do something different? I know that you need to rationalise he denominator by multiplying top and bottom by 3+√2 but I don't know what happens with the ^2 bit.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$ \frac{1}{(3-\sqrt{2})^2} = \frac{1}{11-6\sqrt{2}}$$

Using that $(a-b)^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac1{3-\sqrt2}=\frac{3+\sqrt2}{3^2-2}$$

$$\implies\left(\frac1{3-\sqrt2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{3+\sqrt2}7\right)^2=\frac{(3+\sqrt2)^2}{7^2}$$  and so on